# Top admin bar / toolbar not showing even when logged in, but empty top margin showing?

Tags: admin-bar

I wrote a theme and the top admin / tool bar is not showing. I still see an empty margin. Any ideas?

Here the top margin I never set anywhere in my files.

I actually want to show the toolbar completely.

[image]

Comment: Maybe `wp_footer()` is missing?

Comment: how the heck should I know I _HAVE_ to place this, to achieve this? are there other hidden treasures out there like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your theme is missing the `wp_footer()` function, but is containing the `wp_header()` function.

I can replicate this behavior on the default themes, by removing `wp_footer()`.

The HTML for the admin bar comes from this part in the Core code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
```

It's usually informative to check out the default themes:

The last three lines in the `footer.php` file in the *TwentyTen*, *TwentyEleven*, *TwentyTwelve*, *TwentyThirteen*, *TwentyFourteen* themes are:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that **writing a good theme is not an easy task.**

You only have to read the theme review process on wordpress.org to see the hard work involved.

The following comes through the `wp_head()` function, for logged in users:

- the *admin-bar* stylesheet, is coming

  ```
  <link rel='stylesheet' 
        id='admin-bar-css' 
        href='http://example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=3.8.3'   
        type='text/css' 
        media='all' />
  ```
- the extra white space comes from this part within the `<head>` tags:

  ```
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
      * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
      @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
          html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
          * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
      }
  </style>
  ```

  when the users have the *toolbar option* selected on their profile page:

  [image: toolbar option]
- the part to disable the admin bar when printing:

  ```
  <style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
  ```

To wrap it up:

> If you're logged in, with the toolbar option selected, the theme pages
>   will have an extra  space (`32px`) at the top. This space is filled up with
>   the admin bar HTML blocks from the `wp_footer()`, so make sure you
>   include this function in your theme's footer.

Hope this helps.